# Remapping an XML document into a new XML file with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to remap an XML file using XSLT but I am not familiar with how XSLT goes about this process. Basically I need to convert the following xml:

```
<rows>
<row>
<site id>My Website</site id>
<pageName>Homepage</pageName>
<channel>microsite</channel>
<tree>mywebsite/subsite/homepage</tree>
<url name>brand name</url name>
<urltype>2</urltype>
<spec4>{lang}</spec4>
<spec6>company:section:homepage</spec6>
<spec11>ms:plinth</spec11>
<spec12>2010</spec12>
<spec14>company-{country}</spec14>
<spec15>site:brand name</spec15>
<spec16>Brand Name</spec16>
<spec18></spec18>
<spec30>site:brand name</spec30>
<add4>{lang}</add4>
<add5>ref:company</add5>
<add6>company:section:homepage</add6>
<add11>ms:plinth</add11>
<add12>2010</add12>
<add14>company-{country}</add14>
<add15>site:brand name</add15>
<add16>Brand Name</add16>
<add30>site:brand name</add30>
<actions4>action 1</actions4>
<actions5>action 3</actions5>
</row>
</rows>
```

Into a better structured one:

```
<siteSpecific>
<site id="My Website" urlType="page">
  <general>
    <pageName>ms:sbe:Brand Name:tdr</pageName>
    <channel>microsite</channel>
    <tree>mywebsite/subsite/homepage</tree>
    <urlName>referral:brand</urlName>
    <urlType>2</urlType>
  </general>
  <specs>
    <spec4>{lang}</spec4>
    <spec6>company:section:homepage</spec6>
    <spec11>ms:plinth</spec11>
    <spec12>2010</spec12>
    <spec14>company-{country}</spec14>
    <spec15>site:brand name</spec15>
    <spec16>Brand Name</spec16>
    <spec30>site:brand name</spec30>
  </specs>
  <adds>
    <add4>{lang}</add4>
    <add5>ref:company</add5>
    <add6>company:section:homepage</add6>
    <add11>ms:plinth</add11>
    <add12>2010</add12>
    <add14>company-{country}</add14>
    <add15>site:brand name</add15>
    <add16>Brand Name</add16>
    <add30>site:brand name</add30>
  </adds>
  <actions>
    <actions4>action 1</actions4>
    <actions5>action 3</actions5>
  </actions>
</site>
</siteSpecific>
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I have seen similar posts but which are quite old and as XSLT doesn't seem to be used much for this purpose these days I was also wondering if this is the best option?

Answer (score 2):

Names like `site id` are not allowed in XML so I had to make some assumptions about your input XML. Assuming it is

```
<rows>
<row>
<site_id>My Website</site_id>
<pageName>Homepage</pageName>
<channel>microsite</channel>
<tree>mywebsite/subsite/homepage</tree>
<url_name>brand name</url_name>
<urltype>2</urltype>
<spec4>{lang}</spec4>
<spec6>company:section:homepage</spec6>
<spec11>ms:plinth</spec11>
<spec12>2010</spec12>
<spec14>company-{country}</spec14>
<spec15>site:brand name</spec15>
<spec16>Brand Name</spec16>
<spec18></spec18>
<spec30>site:brand name</spec30>
<add4>{lang}</add4>
<add5>ref:company</add5>
<add6>company:section:homepage</add6>
<add11>ms:plinth</add11>
<add12>2010</add12>
<add14>company-{country}</add14>
<add15>site:brand name</add15>
<add16>Brand Name</add16>
<add30>site:brand name</add30>
<actions4>action 1</actions4>
<actions5>action 3</actions5>
</row>
</rows>
```

then the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="rows">
    <siteSpecific>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </siteSpecific>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <site id="{site_id}" urlType="page">
      <general>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="pageName | channel | tree | url_name | urltype"/>
      </general>
      <specs>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'spec')]"/>
      </specs>
      <adds>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'add')]"/>
      </adds>
      <actions>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'action')]"/>
      </actions>
    </site>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="url_name">
    <urlName>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </urlName>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="urltype">
    <urlType>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </urlType>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

creates the following output:

```
<siteSpecific>
   <site id="My Website" urlType="page">
      <general>
         <pageName>Homepage</pageName>
         <channel>microsite</channel>
         <tree>mywebsite/subsite/homepage</tree>
         <urlName>brand name</urlName>
         <urlType>2</urlType>
      </general>
      <specs>
         <spec4>{lang}</spec4>
         <spec6>company:section:homepage</spec6>
         <spec11>ms:plinth</spec11>
         <spec12>2010</spec12>
         <spec14>company-{country}</spec14>
         <spec15>site:brand name</spec15>
         <spec16>Brand Name</spec16>
         <spec18/>
         <spec30>site:brand name</spec30>
      </specs>
      <adds>
         <add4>{lang}</add4>
         <add5>ref:company</add5>
         <add6>company:section:homepage</add6>
         <add11>ms:plinth</add11>
         <add12>2010</add12>
         <add14>company-{country}</add14>
         <add15>site:brand name</add15>
         <add16>Brand Name</add16>
         <add30>site:brand name</add30>
      </adds>
      <actions>
         <actions4>action 1</actions4>
         <actions5>action 3</actions5>
      </actions>
   </site>
</siteSpecific>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, unfortunately, the transformation is not happening for me, is there something that I should be aware of i.e. what to place within the XML file outside of the link to the XSL sheet?

Comment: Susana, please explain in detail how you are trying to run the transformation when it "is not happening". Are you trying to run an XML to XML transformation in the browser? That only makes sense in my view for result formats like XHTML or SVG or MathML your target browser can handle.